# Modification of a constant value

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, constants

I understand the differences of

```
NSString * const myString = @"Bar"
```

This a immutable pointer to a NSString.

Then we have:

```
NSMutableString const * myMutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Bar"]
```

This is a pointer to a const NSMutableString. The value of myMutableString should not be able to change.

Why can then do?:
[myMutableString append:@"Foo"];

No compiler error, and it works. It allows me to change the value.

In which case can then a constant object be used?

Thanks!

Comment: You are getting confused between the mutability of the object vs the mutability of the reference.  The reference is a constant, but the object it refers to is mutable.

Comment: I think there is some bug in it 
Even i can update reference with constant like

NSMutableString const * myMutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Bar"];
    [myMutableString appendString:@"Hello World"];
    myMutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"HVJHVJHHJ"];

Its compiled and run!

Comment: you should declare your mutable string like `NSMutableString  * const myMutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Foo"];` !! Then you will not able to assign value to it! your declaration is wrong for mutable one. for immutable string it is correct!

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableString const * myMutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Bar"]
```

For this you can change the value of "myMutableString" because it's point to static location, the value of that location may differ but pointing location can not

So, If you have some kind of situation like application base url you have to define which will be the same for every service call in you application the do like below,

1) Easiest way:

```
// Prefs.h
#define APP_BASE_URL @"app_base_url"
```

2) Better way:

```
// Prefs.h
extern NSString * const APP_BASE_URL;

// Prefs.m
NSString * const APP_BASE_URL = @"app_base_url";
```

Benefit of the second is that changing the value of a constant does not cause a rebuild of your entire program.